# содержит ли коллекция тип

Tags: java

Допустим есть Class A
и несколько классов наследников:

```
Class B extends A
Class C extends A
```

и т.д.

Я складываю, к примеру, в ArrayList все или некоторые из наследников.

Дальше мне нужно передать эту коллекцию в метод и если в ней содержатся не все наследники (2 из 2. как в моем примере или n изи n в общем случае), то метод не должен выполняться. То есть я должен проверить, что в коллекции содержатся все наследники. Как мне это сделать, пожалуйста, подскажите

Comment: Рефлексия: пробежать всю коллекцию и проверить классы, используя рефлексию (`instance of A`). Generics: объявить коллекцию таким образом, чтобы туда априори не могли добавить инстансы иных классов.

Comment: Я прошу прощения: понял, что я непонятно объяснил задачу и из за этого возникает двусмысленность. Исправил пост. Суть вот в чем: Дальше мне нужно передать эту коллекцию в метод и если в ней содержатся не все наследники (2 из 2. как в моем примере или n изи n в общем случае), то метод не должен выполняться. То есть я должен проверить, что в коллекции содержатся все наследники.

Comment: Не обязательно использовать `instanceof` - это довольно очень медленный оператор. Вы можете посмотреть в сторону `.getClass().getSimpleName()`.

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от этапа, на котором вам следует решить задачу имеется, по крайней мере, два способа:

**Проверка на этапе компиляции:** (compile time)

На этапе компиляции данную задачу можно решить посредством применения Generic'ов: объявить коллекцию таким образом, чтобы туда априори не могли добавить экземпляры классов, отличных от `A` и его наследников (рассмотрим на примере `List<A>`):

```
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
class D {}

...

void initialMethod() {
    List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new A());
    list.add(new B());
    list.add(new C());
    list.add(new D()); // Error:(25, 18) java: incompatible types: D cannot be converted to A

    callingMethod(list);
}

...

void initialMethod2() {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new A());
    list.add(new B());
    list.add(new C());
    list.add(new D());

    callingMethod(list); // Error:(23, 20) java: incompatible types: java.util.List<java.lang.Object> cannot be converted to java.util.List<A>
}

...

void callingMethod(List<A> list) {
    // непосредственная логика работы метода
}
```

Если же предполагается, что List может быть объявлен (тем, кто использует метод, в который передает коллекцию) без использования Generic'ов, то в таком случае компилятор выдаст warning, но ошибка этапа компиляции получена не будет, в таком случае придется решать проблему на этапе исполнения (см. ниже).

---

**Проверка на этапе исполнения:** (runtime)

На этапе исполнения данную задачу можно решить посредством применения рефлексии: пробежать всю коллекцию и проверить классы, используя какой-либо из способов рефлексии (классический `instance of`, либо объектный `isAssignableFrom`):

```
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
class D {}

...

void initialMethod2() {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(new A());
    list.add(new B());
    list.add(new C());
    list.add(new D());

    callingMethod(list);
}

...

void callingMethod(List list) {
    for (Object item : list) {
        if (item instanceof A) { // либо A.class.isAssignableFrom(item.getClass())
            throw new Exception(""); // либо иной способ обработки
        }
    }

    // непосредственная логика работы метода (поток исполнения дойдет до сюда, только если проверка выше прошла)
}
```

---

**Update:** (после пояснения/обновления вопроса)

Вариант решения через Enum и его наследников:

```
public class SomeTest {
    enum MyEnum {
        FIRST {
            @Override
            String someMethod() {
                return name();
            }
        },

        SECOND {
            @Override
            String someMethod() {
                return name();
            }
        };

        THIRD {
            @Override
            String someMethod() {
                return name();
            }
        };

        abstract String someMethod();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        someMethod(EnumSet.of(MyEnum.FIRST, MyEnum.THIRD));
    }

    static void someMethod(Set<MyEnum> collection) {
        if (collection.size() != MyEnum.values().length) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        // ваша бизнес логика
    }
}
```

Comment: Я прошу прощения: понял, что я непонятно объяснил задачу и из за этого возникает двусмысленность. Исправил пост

Comment: @GrossmasteR после вашей переформулировки ведь ничего не изменилось :)
Либо объявите коллекцию таким образом, чтобы туда просто нельзя было класть что-то отличное от A (см. в ответе вариант с Generic'ами), тогда если туда попытаться класть что-то отличное, а затем попытаться вызвать метод, который в своей сигнатуре это явно объявил, то и программа не будет скомпилирована. Либо сделать то же самое, но посредством рефлексии уже в самом теле метода. Сейчас приведу пример в ответе.

Comment: по-моему, все-таки не совсем так. Дело в том, что мне нужно не найти, будем говорить, лишние элементы, а убедиться, что в коллекции есть все нужные и если кого то не хватает, то сигнализировать об этом

Comment: @GrossmasteR, т.е. вы хотите каким-то образом узнавать о существовании всевозможных наследников определенного класса? Хм, это совсем нетривиальная задача, особенно учитывая тот факт, что ClassLoader грузит классы "лениво", т.е. только при первом обращении к классу, т.е. в конкретный момент времени он сам может не знать не о всех наследниках (а только о тех, к которым прямо сейчас уже обращались), особенно с учетом того, что библиотеки в Java можно загружать динамически (`System.loadLibrary()`).

Comment: @GrossmasteR, возможно я не прав, т.к. не знаю какую именно проблему, на самом деле, вы решаете но мне кажется, что вы её решаете как-то не совсем так, как это следовало бы сделать, чтобы вышло без таких сложностей :)

Comment: да, я сложно и непонятно объяснил, прошу прощения. да и наследование здесь возможно не при чем, по-сути. Вот есть n-ое кол-во типов. все они наследники одного. Ну для примера. A и его наследники B,C и D. Нужно чтобы все три наследника были в коллекции. а если я положил только 2-а из 3-ех, должна быть проверка. Это можно захардкодить, в то же время должно же быть какое-нибудь изящное решение

Comment: @GrossmasteR, угу, я понял суть вашей проблемы, просто сложность в том, чтобы каким-то образом узнать о существовании всевозможных реализаций вашего класса, особенно, с учетом того, что в какой-то библиотеке могут отнаследоваться от вашего класса, тем самым привнеся неоднозначность (точно ли их нужно учитывать?)

Comment: @GrossmasteR, я все еще не знаю, какую бизнесовую задачу вы решаете, но навскидку могу предложить следующее решение: в рамках enum создаете всех нужных наследников (enum'ы - это тоже полноценные классы, в рамках которых можно реализовывать наследование), а в вашем методе в качестве аргумента принимать `Set<ваш_enum>` и проверять его размер (он должен быть == количеству элементов enum, т.е. `Set.size() == Enum.values().length`). Пока что, мне это кажется наименьшим злом :)

Comment: @GrossmasteR добавил в конец ответа пример того, как это могло бы выглядеть на enum.

Comment: как мне кажется, получается не совсем удобно. Мне-то ведь нужен какой-то аналог contains, только чтобы я искал по типу. Есть B, C, D наследники A. кто-то из них лежит в коллекции. Как мне убедиться, что все на месте, а если кого то из трех не хватает, то кого именно?

Comment: @GrossmasteR, если вы заранее точно знаете список наследников, то это сделать несложно, но основная-то проблема как раз-таки в том, что вы ведь просто не знаете список всевозможных наследников, причем список наследников при запуске программы и спустя некоторое время её ипользования банально может измениться (например, class loader мог загрузить новый класс, возможно, даже из динамически подключенной библиотеки), как быть в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 0):

Надо пробежаться циклом по всем элементам `ArrayList` и применить `instanceof A` к каждому элементу.

Если где то не сработает `instanceof` - бинго - вот он элемент, который не является потомком класса `A`

Comment: Я прошу прощения: понял, что я непонятно объяснил задачу и из за этого возникает двусмысленность. Исправил пост.

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно не найти, будем говорить, лишние элементы, а убедиться, что в коллекции есть все нужные и если кого то не хватает, то сигнализировать об этом